# custom spring security form

Tags: spring, spring-security

I would like to add captcha to spring security form, how can I implement this?
I have declared my custom form login like: `<form-login login-page="/login" />` now I need to override authentication filter to verify captcha, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@misha, take a look at this article: [Spring Security 3: Integrating reCAPTCHA Service](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-security-3-integrating-recaptcha.html).

This uses two filters to make reCAPTCHA integration as seamless and unobstrusive as possible. That means your existing Spring Security implementation will not break. No need to touch existing classes.

There's no need to override your existing implementation. You can add CAPTCHA to your existing implementation.

Comment: hmm, is it thread safe? as I haven't seen neither ThreadLocal storage nor scoped or some other scope like request. But anyway article is great. It showed me one more way to implement captcha verification. I did it slightly different. I have subclassed DaoAuthenticationProvider and put verification code there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can override `attemptAuthentication` method as following (pseudo code):

`1. get captcha response`

`2. verify captcha response`

`3. if invalid response, throw some kind of AuthenticationException (may be named as  CaptchaFailedException) that you can check in your custom AuthenticationFailureHandler`

`4. if valid response, call super.attemptAuthentication(request,response)`

Comment: The default authentication failure handler (SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler), saves the exception in session as session.setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, exception); If you are using this default class (or extending it) then you can use that exception from session in JSP and show an appropriate message. Please also see forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=91833